# NullPointerException textView.setText()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

i'am here because i cant figured out why i'am getting a nullPointerException with no valid reason, i also do a try and catch block to help me figure the issue but the message is null and the printStackTrace is (void), this issue is occuring in a array loop, in the first item it's everything allright but in the second it's throws NullPointerExcption.

```
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moody/activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at fragments.TopicsPreview.createTopicsContent(TopicsPreview.java:162) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at fragments.TopicsPreview.createTopicsRows(TopicsPreview.java:85) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at fragments.TopicsPreview.onCreateView(TopicsPreview.java:59) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929) 
09-16 14:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4332): ... 11 more
```

[Debug Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DISKs.png)

```
protected void createTopicsContent(MoodleCourseContent[] courseContent,
        LayoutInflater inflater, LinearLayout insertPoint, String courseId) {

    for (int j = 0; j < courseContent.length; j++) {

        final LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        View topicsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topics_preview_context,
                null);
        TextView topicName = (TextView) topicsView
                .findViewById(R.id.topic_label);

        topicName.setText(courseContent[j].getName());

        // Loop for the modules array
        MoodleModule[] modules = courseContent[j].getMoodleModules();

        for (int i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {

            final TextView topicModule = (TextView) topicsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.content_preview_textView);
            if (!modules[i].getName().isEmpty()) {

                try {
                    topicModule.setText(modules[i].getName());
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    e.getMessage();
                }

            }

            // Where the textview id will be course id and the textview
            // tag will be the topic id
            topicModule.setId(Integer.parseInt(courseId));
            topicModule.setTag(Long.toString(modules[i].getId()));

            row.addView(topicsView);
            insertPoint.addView(row);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no need to inflate your view and initialize textview everytime in a loop. initialize once and append text to textview

Comment: try ´topicModule.append(modules[i].getName());´

Comment: no!? i'am creating several textView's and several View's and adding them to a LinearLayout

Comment: OK this i bad structured i will restruct and give it a try, also will try topicModule.append

Comment: Check if you used the correct ID to set topicModule. Also, check if topicModule is null after the findViewById

Comment: I already checked topicModule it's not null, now i'am sure it's bad structured I've already did this but with JSON now i'am doing again to an external lib, and i the rush i'am i made a mistake when converting the method to work with the external lib, i will re-struct and if the issues persists i will update the post, thanks guys

Comment: It's solved was several structure problems, because i was doing this without checking null array's and other several mistakes, this is the result of developing when we are in a rush. Thanks all for the time spent ;)

PS: Can the admin's delete this, this question will not help anybody

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code outside of the onCreate method. The log says 'Unable to start activity' this happens when something in the onCreate method throws an exception. This also could be a reason this code fails,  textviews aren't initialized yet.

Try running this code in the onResume method.

Comment: You can call setText inside onCreate on any TextView.

Comment: It's solved was several structure problems, because i was doing this without checking null array's and other several mistakes, this is the result of developing when we are in a rush. Thanks all for the time spent ;)

PS: Can the admin's delete this, this question will not help anybody

Answer (score 0):

It's solved was several structure problems, because i was doing this without checking null array's and other several mistakes, this is the result of developing when we are in a rush. Thanks all for the time spent ;) PS: Can the admin's delete this, this question will not help anybody